# Initialize multiple Tiny MCE RTE in one page using single function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I have to load 5 rich text editors - TinyMCE RTEs in one page.
Generally to load single Timy MCE, I am using the below code:

```
var _setTinymce = function () {
        var ed = new tinymce.Editor('textAreaContent', {
            menubar: 'edit insert view format table',
            plugins: ["autolink fullscreen table lists link image charmap print preview anchor code "],
            toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | bold italic |  underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | strikethrough | superscript | subscript | code | removeformatbullist | numlist outdent indent | link  image | fontselect ",
            browser_spellcheck: true,
            relative_urls: false,
            }, tinymce.EditorManager);
        ed.render();
    };
```

**textAreaContent** is the ID of my text area in the html.

In document.ready, I am calling this function _setTinymce();
This works absolutely fine.

Now I have to load this TinyMCE RTE in multiple text areas(nearly 7)
I dont want to repeat the same code(given above).

I have taken an array which contains all the textareas IDs.

```
var rteDisplay = [textAreaContent ,textAreaContent1, textAreaContent2, textAreaContent3, textAreaContent4 ];
```

I have a common function to which I am passing text area ID as a parameter.
But the RTEs dont load.

I am getting error:

```
tinymce.min.js:53 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'visibility' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

The array you have is not passing Strings so I suspect they are being interpreted as variables and are `undefined`...perhaps you need to do this"

```
var rteDisplay = ['textAreaContent' ,'textAreaContent1', 'textAreaContent2',
                  'textAreaContent3', 'textAreaContent4' ];
```